# Apache Airflow - trigger/schedule DAG rerun on completion (File Sensor)

Tags: triggers, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Good Morning.

I'm trying to setup a DAG too

1. Watch/sense for a file to hit a network folder
2. Process the file
3. Archive the file

Using the tutorials online and stackoverflow I have been able to come up with the following DAG and Operator that successfully achieves the objectives, however I would like the DAG to be rescheduled or rerun on completion so it starts watching/sensing for another file.

I attempted to set a variable `max_active_runs:1` and then a `schedule_interval: timedelta(seconds=5)` this yes reschedules the DAG but starts queuing task and locks the file.

Any ideas welcome on how I could rerun the DAG after the archive_task?

Thanks

DAG CODE

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator, OmegaFileSensor, ArchiveFileOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import Variable

default_args = {
    'owner': 'glsam',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'provide_context': True,
    'retries': 100,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30),
    'max_active_runs': 1,
    'schedule_interval': timedelta(seconds=5),
}

dag = DAG('test_sensing_for_a_file', default_args=default_args)

filepath = Variable.get("soucePath_Test")
filepattern = Variable.get("filePattern_Test")
archivepath = Variable.get("archivePath_Test")

sensor_task = OmegaFileSensor(
    task_id='file_sensor_task',
    filepath=filepath,
    filepattern=filepattern,
    poke_interval=3,
    dag=dag)


def process_file(**context):
    file_to_process = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(
        key='file_name', task_ids='file_sensor_task')
    file = open(filepath + file_to_process, 'w')
    file.write('This is a test\n')
    file.write('of processing the file')
    file.close()


proccess_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_the_file', 
    python_callable=process_file,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

archive_task = ArchiveFileOperator(
    task_id='archive_file',
    filepath=filepath,
    archivepath=archivepath,
    dag=dag)

sensor_task >> proccess_task >> archive_task
```

FILE SENSOR OPERATOR

```py
import os
import re

from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator


class ArchiveFileOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, filepath, archivepath, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArchiveFileOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.archivepath = archivepath
        
    def execute(self, context):
        file_name = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(
            'file_sensor_task', key='file_name')
        os.rename(self.filepath + file_name, self.archivepath + file_name)


class OmegaFileSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, filepath, filepattern, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OmegaFileSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.filepattern = filepattern

    def poke(self, context):
        full_path = self.filepath
        file_pattern = re.compile(self.filepattern)

        directory = os.listdir(full_path)

        for files in directory:
            if re.match(file_pattern, files):
                context['task_instance'].xcom_push('file_name', files)
                return True
        return False


class OmegaPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "omega_plugin"
    operators = [OmegaFileSensor, ArchiveFileOperator]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `schedule_interval=None`  and use `airflow trigger_dag` command from `BashOperator` to launch next execution at the completion of the previous one.

```
trigger_next = BashOperator(task_id="trigger_next", 
           bash_command="airflow trigger_dag 'your_dag_id'", dag=dag)

sensor_task >> proccess_task >> archive_task >> trigger_next
```

You can start your first run manually with the same `airflow trigger_dag` command and then `trigger_next` task will automatically trigger the next one. We use this in production for many months now and and it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

Dmitris method worked perfectly.

I also found in my reading setting `schedule_interval=None` and then using the TriggerDagRunOperator worked equally as well

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_dag_RBCPV99_rerun',
    trigger_dag_id="RBCPV99_v2",
    dag=dag)

sensor_task >> proccess_task >> archive_task >> trigger
```

Comment: How did you get  this to work without the use of a `python_callable`? I have a  similar use case and would like to know exactly how you did this. Thank you!

Comment: **@CodingInCircles** AFAICS `python_callable` is an *optional* parameter in [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py)