# Dynamic task definition in Airflow

Tags: python, bash, airflow, orchestration

I’m currently trying to use Airflow to orchestrate a process where some operators are defined dynamically and depend on the output of another (earlier) operator.

In the code below t1 updates a text file with new records (these are actually read from an external queue but, for simplicity, I hard coded them as  A, B and C here). Then, I want to create separate operators for each record read from that text file. These operators will create directories A, B and C, respectively, and in Airflow UI will be seen as separate bash processes Create_directory_A, Create_directory_B and Create_directory_C.

```
dag = DAG('Test_DAG',
          description="Lorem ipsum.",
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20),
          schedule_interval=None,
          catchup=False)


def create_text_file(list_of_rows):
    text_file = open('text_file.txt', "w")
    for row in list_of_rows:
        text_file.write(row + '\n')
    text_file.close()


def read_text():
    txt_file = open('text_file.txt', 'r')
    return [element for element in txt_file.readlines()]


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Create_text_file',
    python_callable=create_text_file,
    op_args=[['A', 'B', 'C']],
    dag=dag
)

for row in read_text():
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='Create_directory_{}'.format(row),
        bash_command="mkdir {{params.dir_name}}",
        params={'dir_name': row},
        dag=dag
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

In [Airflow’s documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file) I can see that *the scheduler will execute it [DAG] periodically to reflect the changes if any*. Does that mean that there is a risk that, even though my t1 operator is executed before t2, the bash operators are created for the list of records before the update (as that's when the DAG was evaluated)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot create tasks dynamically that depend on the output of an upstream task. You're mixing up schedule and execution time. A DAG *definition* and a *task* is created at schedule time. A DAG *run* and *task instance* is created at execution time. Only a task *instance* can produce output.

The Airflow scheduler will build the dynamic graph with whatever `text_file.txt` contains at *schedule time*. These tasks are then shipped off to the workers.

A worker will eventually execute the `t1` task instance and create a new `text_file.txt`, but at this point, the list of `t2` tasks has already been calculated by the scheduler and sent off to the workers.

So, whatever the latest `t1` task instance dumps into `text_file.txt` will be used the next time the scheduler decides it's time to run the DAG.

If your task is fast and your workers are not backlogged, that will be the contents from the previous DAG run. If they are backlogged, `text_file.txt` contents may be stale, and if you're really unlucky, the scheduler reads the file while a task instance is writing to it, and you'll get incomplete data from `read_text()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How can we make sure that t1 runs before t2? Is this related to SubDAGs?

Comment: That's what the `t1 >> t2` does - it builds up a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) of tasks that describes in which order tasks should be run.

Answer (score 4):

This code will actually create one instance of `t2` which will be bash operator built with the last `row` it gets from `read_text()`. I am certain this is not what you want.

A better approach would be to create a separate DAG for your `t2` operator which is triggered when the file is written by `t1`. There's a SO question on this that might help: [Apache Airflow - trigger/schedule DAG rerun on completion (File Sensor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770070/apache-airflow-trigger-schedule-dag-rerun-on-completion-file-sensor)

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I realized I missed additional square brackets in `t1`. As it stands, the code does generate `t2` for all rows read from `read_text()`. Is there ever a risk that the list of rows it gets is outdated?

Comment: Ah, OK. I still think a separate DAG would be cleaner and easier to maintain, I would not rely on this working as it is. Multiple DAGs are pretty common on Airflow/

Comment: What might be a good approach to: Query a table on a schedule, and, if found, for every row, run tasks?