# Create tasks dynamically in airflow with external file

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, orchestration

I am trying to create a DAG that generates tasks dynamically based on a JSON file located in storage. I followed this guide step-by-step:

https://bigdata-etl.com/apache-airflow-create-dynamic-dag/

But the DAG gets stuck with the following message:

[image: Dag getting stuck]

Is it possible to read an external file and use it to create tasks dynamically in Composer? I can do this when I read data only from an airflow Variable, but when I read an external file, the dag gets stuck in the `isn't available in the web server's DagBag object` state. I need to read from an external file as the contents of the JSON will change with every execution.

I am using `composer-1.8.2-airflow-1.10.2`.

I read this answer to a similar question:

[Dynamic task definition in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825335/dynamic-task-definition-in-airflow)

But I am not trying to create the tasks based on a separate task, only based on the external file.

This is my second approach that also get's stuck in that error state:

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import json
import os

products = json.loads(Variable.get("products"))

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 10),
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'json_test2',
        default_args=default_args,
        # Not scheduled, trigger only
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:


        # Print the dag_run's configuration, which includes information about the
        # Cloud Storage object change.
        def read_json_file(file_path):
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                    return json.load(f)

        def get_run_list(files):
            run_list = []
            #The file is uploaded in the storage bucket used as a volume by Composer
            last_exec_json = read_json_file("/home/airflow/gcs/data/last_execution.json")
            date = last_exec_json["date"]
            hour = last_exec_json["hour"]
            for file in files:
                #Testing by adding just date and hour
                name = file['name']+f'_{date}_{hour}'
                run_list.append(name)
            return run_list

        rl = get_run_list(products)

        start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)
        end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', dag=dag)

        for name in rl:
            tsk = DummyOperator(task_id=name, dag=dag)
            start >> tsk >> end
```

Comment: Check your webserver logs, most likely there is an error importing your DAG into the DAGBag

Comment: Your answer describes the exact same steps that I followed but it doesn't work. I'll retry later and update you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create DAG that generates task dynamically based on a `JSON` file, which is located in a Cloud Storage bucket. I followed guide, that you provided, and it works perfectly in my case.

Firstly you need to upload your JSON configuration file to `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` directory, and then DAG python file to the same path (you can find the path in `airflow.cfg` file, which is located in the bucket).

Later on, you will be able to see DAG in Airflow UI:

[image]

As you can see the log `DAG isn't available in the web server's DagBag object`, the DAG isn't available on Airflow Web Server. However, the DAG can be scheduled as active because Airflow Scheduler is working independently with the Airflow Web Server.

When a lot of DAGs are loaded at once to a Composer environment, it may overload on the environment. As the Airflow webserver is on a Google-managed project, only certain types of updates will cause the webserver container to be restarted, like adding or upgrading one of the PyPI packages or changing an Airflow setting. The workaround is to add a dummy environment variable:

- Open Composer instance in GCP
- `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE` tab
- `Edit`, then add environment variable and `Submit`

You can use following command to restart it:

```
gcloud composer environments update ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}  --location=${ENV_LOCATION}  --update-airflow-configs=core-dummy=true
gcloud composer environments update ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}  --location=${ENV_LOCATION}  --remove-airflow-configs=core-dummy
```

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.